# Xamarin Forms Change the Text of MenuItem

Tags: xamarin.forms, menuitem

Is it possible to change in a ListView the text of the menu item when it is clicked, like change it from complete to incomplete?

Comment: could you explain more,and paste code ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ItemTapped event.

Example should work, but I didn't test that.

**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="Incomplete"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**C#**

```
    public void OnItemTapped (object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listElement = e.Item as ListElement;
            if(listItem.Text == "Incomplete")
            {
               listElement.Text = "Complete";
            }
            else
               listElement.Text = "Incomplete"; 
        }
```

**More informations:**
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#selectiontaps